# _asm swap and compiler additions

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-construction, x86

I've just written a bubble_sort of an integer array (see previous question) and decided to ignore the standard swap and implement an assembly swap, which looks like this:

```
int swap(int* x, int* y)
{
if(x != y)
  {
       _asm
      {
        mov eax,[x];
        mov ebx, [y];
        mov [y],eax;
        mov [x], ebx;
      }
    }
return 0;
}
```

I was actually sure that it will be inserted into the resulting code as is and will work.
Well, my code which uses this swap does work, but I've looked into what the complier turned it into, and my swap was changed into this:

```
if(x != y)
00E01A6F  inc         ebp  
00E01A70  or          byte ptr [ebx],bh  
00E01A72  inc         ebp  
00E01A73  or          al,74h  
if(x != y)
00E01A75  or          al,8Bh  
  {
       _asm
      {
        mov eax,[x];
00E01A77  inc         ebp  
00E01A78  or          byte ptr [ebx+45890C5Dh],cl  
        mov [y],eax;
00E01A7E  or          al,89h  
        mov [x], ebx;
00E01A80  pop         ebp  
00E01A81  or          byte ptr [ebx],dh  
      }
   }
return 0;
00E01A83  rcr         byte ptr [edi+5Eh],5Bh  
}
```

I've compiled it in MS VS 2012.
What do all those extra lines mean, and why are they there? Why can't my _asm fragment just be used?

Comment: Are you sure that's your swap?

Comment: Where does that disassembly come from? It looks seriously mangled. Is it the output from the assembler, or the debugger? Or something else?

Comment: You have got optimizations ON ???

Comment: it's from the debugger. it might in fact be mixed up with something related to a different part of my code, but it's hard for me to tell - i'm an _asm novice.

Comment: @Anon: optimisation is disabled for all functions that contain asm blocks, isn't it?

Comment: @Chiffa: Ask the compiler to give you an assembly listing.

Comment: @TonyK:-AFAIK Standards just say The asm declaration is conditionally-supported; its meaning is implementation-defined.Rest depends on vendor.

Comment: If these lines make no sense, please learn assembly before continuing.

Comment: @Cole: Do they make sense to you? Why is the compiler generating `or al,74h` followed by `or al,8Bh`? Quite apart from the irrelevance of these lines, if I were a compiler I would prefer the crisper code `or al,FFh`.

Comment: @TonyK they make sense to me - well not "as is", but if you look at the bytes differently.

Comment: @harold: So are you going to reveal the secret?

Comment: @TonyK if you skip the first two bytes it starts making sense. My answer has more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's missing the first and last bytes. If you look at what the code is now:

```
inc ebp                    ; 45
or byte ptr [ebx],bh       ; 08 3B
inc ebp                    ; 45
or al,74h                  ; 0C 74
or al,8Bh                  ; 0C 8B
inc ebp                    ; 45
or byte ptr [ebx+45890C5Dh],cl ; 08 8B 5D 0C 89 45
or al,89h                  ; 0C 89
pop ebp                    ; 5B
or byte ptr [ebx],dh       ; 08 33
rcr byte ptr [edi+5Eh],5Bh ; C0 5F 5E 5B
```

If you ignore the first two bytes, you get this:

```
  cmp eax, [ebp + 12] ; 3B 45 0C
  jz skip             ; 74 0C
  mov eax, [ebx + 8]  ; 8B 45 08
  mov ebx, [ebp + 12] ; 8B 5D 0C 
  mov [ebp + 12], eax ; 89 45 0C 
  mov [ebx + 8], ebx  ; 89 5B 08 
skip:
  xor eax, eax        ; 33 C0
  pop edi             ; 5F
  pop esi             ; 5E
  pop ebp             ; 5B
```

It's missing the ret at the end, and, crucially, some instruction that has `eax` and `[ebp + 8]` as arguments (a `mov` would make sense there). The missing first byte desynchronized the disassembly with the instruction stream.

It's also missing the prologue, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Can you tell us how you've compiled that function and how you got the disassembly?

When I compile using

```
cl /FAsc -c test.c
```

I get the following in the assembly listing for the inline assembler part:

```
; 4    :   {
; 5    :        _asm
  0000a 53       push    ebx
; 6    :       {
; 7    :         mov eax,[x];
  0000b 8b 44 24 08  mov     eax, DWORD PTR _x$[esp]
; 8    :         mov ebx, [y];
  0000f 8b 5c 24 0c  mov     ebx, DWORD PTR _y$[esp]
; 9    :         mov [y],eax;
  00013 89 44 24 0c  mov     DWORD PTR _y$[esp], eax
; 10   :         mov [x], ebx;
  00017 89 5c 24 08  mov     DWORD PTR _x$[esp], ebx
; 4    :   {
; 5    :        _asm
  0001b 5b       pop     ebx
$LN4@swap:
; 11   :       }
```

One thing to note is that you aren't swapping what you'd really like to swap - your swapping the pointers that are passed to the function, not the items the pointers refer to.  So when the function returns, the swapped data is thrown away. The function is just one big nop.

You might want to try somethign like:

```
   _asm
  {
    mov eax,[x];
    mov ebx,[y];

    mov ecx, [eax]
    mov edx, [ebx]

    mov [eax], edx
    mov [ebx], ecx
  }
```

But frankly, performing the swap in C would likely result in similar (or better) code.

Comment: #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    int my_swap(int x, int y)
    {
    if(x != y)
      {
        _asm
       {
     mov eax,[x];
        mov ebx,[y];
    
        mov ecx, [eax]
        mov edx, [ebx]
    
        mov [eax], edx
        mov [ebx], ecx
         }
      }
    return 0;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
     int a=10, b=20;
     cout << "a = " << a << " b = " << b << endl;
    my_swap(a,b);
    cout << "a = "<<a << " b = "<< b << endl;
    return 0;
    }

Comment: eax ebx and ecx are the only ones guaranteed to be ok?

Comment: @Chiffa: the arguments to `my_swap()` need to be pointers: `int my_swap(int* x, int* y)`.

Comment: @Cole: From MSDN: "When using __asm to write assembly language in C/C++ functions, you don't need to preserve the EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, or EDI registers". Using `ebx`, `esi` or `edi` will cause the compiler to save/restore them since a function needs to preserve their values.

Comment: @MichaelBurr it must to be compliment*

Comment: Can I ask how his code is one big no op? Because to me `mov eax, [x]` should load the value pointed to by x into eax unless I'm missing something

Comment: @Cole: `mov eax,[x]` moves the data at the address of `x` into `eax`.  But `x` is just an argument to the function (more or less a local variable).  So swapping `[x]` and `[y]` just swaps the two locals. When the function returns those variables are discarded.  If you want to swap using a function in C you have to pass pointers. When `x` is a pointer, `mov eax,[x]` loads the pointer into `eax`; to get the pointed to value you need to then load what `eax` points to.  Something like `mov ecx, [eax]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push at the beginning and pop in the end if you want to see the end of main() :)

```
 _asm
  {
    push eax     //back-up of registers
    push ebx
    mov eax,[x];
    mov ebx, [y];
    mov [y],eax;
    mov [x], ebx;
    pop ebx      //resume the registers where they were
    pop eax      // so, compiler can continue working normally
  }
```

Because compiler uses them for other things too!

You could also have used `xchg`

```
mov eax,[x]
xchg   eax, [y]
mov   [x],eax
```

You 64 bit? Then there is a single read, single swap, single write. You can search it.

Good day!

Comment: This doesn't explain why the compiler emit the code in the OP.

Comment: Are you sure, tuğrul? I don't know all the details of the calling convention used by MS, but I would expect that using `eax`, at least, would be safe.

Comment: Well, thanks, ans, since I am 64 bit, perhaps you might direct me to a easy-to-understand guide to 64-bit C optimization?

Comment: eax and ebx are guaranteed to be volatile, no?

Comment: @TonyK eax is the return value in cdecl

Comment: @Chiffa: you might be running on a 64-bit Windows, but your program is not 64-bit if you're compiling with MSVC.  MSVC doesn't support `asm` blocks when building for x64.

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık: the eax, ebx, ecx, edx, esi, and edi do not need to be preserved in an asm block.